# typescript generic function index constraint

Tags: function, typescript, generics

is there a way to specify something that behaves as this suggests?

```
function fn<T, U extends keyof T, T[U] extends number>()
```

i cannot get "T[U] extends number" part to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
function fn<T extends Record<U, number>, U extends keyof T>(t: T, u: U): number {
  return t[u];
}
```

By saying that `T extends Record<U, number>` you are essentially saying that `T[U]` exists and is of type `number` (or some subtype):

```
fn({ name: 'fred', age: 40 }, 'age');  // okay
fn({ name: 'fred', age: 40 }, 'name');  // error
fn({ name: 'fred', age: 40 }, 'oops');  // error
```

Does that work for you?